# Can a folder be renamed in ms dos if the name will change?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, file-rename

Its there a way to rename a folder in batch command, if we don't know the name?

Let's say the name of the folder will begin with `comp`, but after that may contain numbers or letters like `comp58952`

How can I rename it to just `comp`?

Comment: What's wrong with `ren comp_20 comp`?

Comment: Windows CMD != MS-DOS!

Comment: the _20 can change in the future... and can be comp_21, and when I run the batch file to rename whatever will be after comp folder name...

Comment: Your question is too broad for this site, because at the moment you are basically asking us to search a proper command for you. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve]! Then [edit] your question accordingly...

Comment: That's not what you asked, and it's information that should be in your post. You should [edit] and ask the question you really want answered, so you're not wasting both your time and ours. :-) What happens if `comp` already exists? What do you want to happen then? Unless you're **really** using MS-DOS (which has not even been available on Windows for at least a decade now), you should also remove *ms dos* from the title.

Comment: Your question is unclear, especially given your comment above. Is it possible that you want to rename the directory, to the same name minus the 5th, 6th and 7th characters?

Comment: Yes @Compo, but I don't know how many chars will be after comp...

Comment: You keep adding details in comments (both here and to the answer). STOP. Instead, [edit] your question and make it clear **there** what it is you're asking, where people can see the details. It does no good to bury important details in comment clutter, and we shouldn't be having to play *20 questions* in the comments asking you to explain what you want to do. Please [edit] the question. Thanks.

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir comp* /AD-H /B 2^>nul') do if /I not "%%I" == "comp" if not exist "comp" ren "%%I" "comp"` might work in your batch file if the current working directory on execution of the batch file is the directory containing the folder with name matching wildcard pattern `comp*`.

Answer (score -1):

```
ren comp_* comp
```

This accounts for future name changes. 
* is wildcard. It can be anything. You can also do it like I'm showing below here if the number is always two digits.:

```
ren comp_?? comp
```

Comment: This will also rename `comp_me`. The poster has not been specific enough with the question to allow an answer yet. For instance, what happens if `comp` already exists? What happens if there is more than one `comp_*` match (for example, `comp_1` and `comp_2`? What should happen then, as both of them can't be renamed to `comp`?

Comment: only one folder at a time and after rename from let's say comp20 to only comp, will be moved from same batch file.

Comment: if it didn't work with full filepath, you probably need quotes around your paths. Also the 2nd parameter "comp" doesn't need the full path just your first parameter "comp_22". ren "C:\anotherfolder\comp_??" comp

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made a folder comp_42 and with the command ren C:\a\comp_??  comp dosent work, but with ren C:\a\comp_42  comp its working... windows 10

Comment: Sure, also does this work?  rename "C:\a\comp_*" comp
I'm surprised that the ?s aren't working for you.